# How to pass the id of the element user clicked on back to Flask using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, flask

I am trying to work on this website that shows a list of records, and when a user clicks on one of them, he will be navigated to another page that shows the details of the record. The logic behind it is, each 'li' tag has an "id" attribute that is unique, and I can use that id to call API and fetch the detailed info for that record. However, it seems that nothing was passed back to Flask...

HTML code:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  {%for i in range(0,length)%}
  <li class="list-group-item" id={{res.value[i].id}}>
    <h4 class="itemName">Name:{{res.value[i].name}}</h4>
    <p class="itemAssetType">{{res.value[i].assetTypes[0]}}</p>
    <p class="itemQualifiedName">{{res.value[i].qualifiedName}}</p>   
  </li>
  {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function(){
$('li').click(function(){
    var elementID = this.id
    var datatosend = JSON.stringify({"guid":elementID})
    $.ajax({
        url: '/details',
        data: datatosend,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            window.location.href = '/details'
            console.log(response); //for stackoverflow: this shows None in console
        },
        error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
    });
});
```

});

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/details',methods=['POST','GET'])
def details():
    print (request.json) #this gives: None
    print (request.data) #this gives: b''
    print (request.args.get("guid")) #this gives: None
    return str(request.json)
```

Just wondering how am I supposed to pass that id into flask?? Why is it always empty???
I am kinda new to the front end, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you remove this part

```
success: function(response){
                window.location.href = '/details'
                console.log(response);
            }
```

because you get some data from server and then you go another page? but your data still stands in previous page!
You need to keep stay in current page and use your data like this:

```
  success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('li').click(function () {
    var elementID = this.id;
    console.log(this.id)//for stackoverflow: this shows the id as I expected
    $.ajax({
      url: '/details',
      data: { guid: this.id },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(error);
        console.log('element id =======>',elementID)//it is work now!!!
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li id="xyz">##click me##</li>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for helping! however, the result remained the same...the 'this.id' is empty (undefined) may be the main issue..

Comment: I have just updated my answer to fix your bug. the problem  occurs because error function does not work in your element scope you can use es6+ arrow functions or function closure technique like me to get this.id from clicked element.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, I really appreciate it! And now the value has been passed to the var elementID. Sorry but this still doesn't work, like the ajax was still failed. The main purpose was to pass the elementID back to Flask, and it is not yet accomplished. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!!

Comment: Just updated the question, hope the question is clearer now!!

Comment: I check my answer with this website https://hookbin.com/  and ajax send guid:'xyz' so your javascript code is ok. Your question is about flask now. But I have never use flask.

Comment: No problem! Thanks!!